# How to handle ajax/http-post request (responsetype: arraybuffer) using nodejs+express in the backend

Tags: ajax, node.js, express, http-post, arraybuffer

Situation : Client js sends ajax request to nodejs express server.

Client

```
xmlHttpRequest=new XMLHttpRequest();  
xmlHttpRequest.open("POST","/some/server/path,true);
xmlHttpRequest.responseType="arraybuffer";
xmlHttpRequest.send(new Uint8Array(arraybufferobject));
```

Server(so far)

```
var express = require('express');
var server = express();
server.use(express.static(__dirname));
server.use(express.bodyParser());
server.post('/goforms/modbus/',function(req,res,next){
    //How to access the uint8array || arraybuffer ?
});

server.listen(80);
```

Im stuck at this point. How to access the HTTP POST data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bodyParser middleware does not parse POSTed binary data. When i tried base64 encoded strings, it would show up as the object name in a JSON object, something like {"data":}, obviously expecting POST-data in the form name=value.

There might be a middleware that deals with binary data, or you can access the raw data by binding to the "data" event and stack the received chunks into a buffer using the method described in the [ProtocolBuffers.js wiki](https://github.com/dcodeIO/ProtoBuf.js/wiki/How-to-read-binary-data-in-the-browser-or-under-node.js).

This is using the vanilla http module without express, but should work anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about arraybuffer but usually, we can access the POST data using the req.body parameter. Does that work for you?

Comment: its empty .. reg.body = {}